# Android return to same activity finish old one

Tags: android

Hello I have a list activity getting data from internet and a search activity. 
When user press search button search activity starts and gets filters from user. Then when user press go button main (list) activity starts and search activity finishes. Main activity shows search results.

The problem is when user press back button on phone  search result activity disappears and old list shows up.

```
A --> B --> A (B is finished)
A --> A    (this is activity stack, lets make another search)
A --> A --> B --> A (b is finished)
A --> A --> A   (ovvv noo)
```

How i can force to close previous activity when new one is called?

I tried launchmode, nohistory true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the Intent flags, and I think the one interesting for you is: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

when you call the new activity finish the current one like so:

```
finish();
```

Also read this: [Android LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Comment: This will end the Activity, but I'm pretty sure there's a launch mode that will work better for what he's describing.

Comment: "How i can force to close previous activity" - poor grammar makes it unclear

Comment: thanks for help Erik. I also use finish();
I meant the previous of same activity.
In may question A --> B --> A (B is finished)
B starts A and finishes itself. So there is 2 A activity in activity stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **android:launchMode="singleTop"** for your "A" activity. Be aware that in this case [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method will be called inside your "A" activity and your activity should react on it appropriately to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

*You can use* *`android:launchMode="singleTask"`*

The conclusion -

```
A --> B (B is finished)
A (this is activity stack, lets make another search)
A --> B (b is finished)
A (ovvv yes)
```

You will never have other instance of your activity A Or B.

**singleTask**

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want but instead of finish your activity, you can chose to do something with the "back button"

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {
        // TODO what you want 

        Intent intent = new Intent(ChoixPiecesJustificativesActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```