# how to intent the same activity instead of second activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to intent same activity such as MainActivity->MainActivity instead of MainActivity->SecondActivity

Her is my code, but it doesn't work, it will stop my app, how to fix it

```
 public class AddasMessage extends AsyncTask<AddMessage,Long,JSONArray>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(FriendDetailsActivity.this);


    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog.setMessage("Adding...");
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(AddMessage... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

        return params[0].AddtobeMessage();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        Log.i("Main activity", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
        dialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FriendDetailsActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "You are success to send the message!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();



    }



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android return to same activity finish old one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890181/android-return-to-same-activity-finish-old-one)

Comment: 04-22 07:11:23.210 1874-1874/slidenerd.vivz.navigationviewdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at slidenerd.vivz.view.FriendDetailsActivity.onCreate(FriendDetailsActivity.java:75)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to refresh our activity, try this

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

or try this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call method

```
  recreate();
```