# 1000 questions in android need to create 1000 activities?

Tags: android

I'm doing a app that will ask question to users like:

> what is the capital of australia?
>
> Camberra - paris - washington - toquio

and I will have 4 options, so user can select the right one.

When it choose the answer the next question will show.

I'd like to know if I need to create one activity for each of this questions/answers or there is another method? can I have examples?

Comment: You can simply change content on the screen dynamically.

Comment: you can use recyclerview for to show your questions.....https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Use View pager and adapter, that will add swipe option

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792153/how-to-intent-the-same-activity-instead-of-second-activity

Comment: @LeoLeontev oh, intent sending the question number to the same activity and do a if/else could be a good choose?

Answer (score 1):

'You can use Viewpager or viewFlipper for that purpose. in this way you can show all of your's questions in one activity'

Answer (score 1):

I would change dynamically the content of the question and answers components.

If you animate the changes in those components it will look really nice and you'll be saving resources that you would waste creating an activity for each question.